# what is the xml mapping for json like this?

Tags: mybatis

Tables:

```
Create table development(
  developmentName varchar(100) primary key,
  description varchar(100)
); 

Create table Student(
  name varchar(100) primary key,
  dateType varchar(100),
  developmentName foreign key reference development(developmentName)
);
```

Input Json:

```
The json would come in the format

{ "DevelopmentName":"comp", "description":"Descrizione Tracciatro 1", "Student":[ {

        "name":"String",
        "dateType":"String", 
        "DevelopmentName":"comp"
     },
    {
        "name":"String",
        "date_type":"String"
        "DevelopmentName":"comp"
     }]}
```

`DevelopmentName` is primary key and which is foreign key for Student.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="it.eng.billing.mapper.Development">
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="it.eng.billing.model.Development">
    <result column="DevelopmentName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="DevelopmentName" />
    <result column="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="description" />
  </resultMap>


    <insert id="insert" parameterType="it.eng.billing.model.Development" >
    insert into Development (DevelopmentName, description) values (#{DevelopmentName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},#{description,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
  </insert>
 <insert id="insertOptions" parameterType="it.eng.billing.model.Student">
 INSERT INTO Student (name,DevelopmentName, datatype)
VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="option" open="(" separator="),(" close=")" >
        #{option.name},#{option.DevelopmentName},#{option.datatype}
    </foreach> 
  </insert>
</mapper>
```

There is problem with the XML. The json is not getting saved into database.

```
public interface DevelopmentMapper{
default void save(DevelopmentDto record) {
      insert(record);
      insertOptions(record.getStudent());
}
```

from service class, calling developmentMapper.save(DevelopmentDto obj)

Comment: Please specify more clearly what is the problem. mybatis deals with mapping between java objects and the database. JSON is just a format. What do you do with it? What object types are you using in mapper methods? What is the signature of the mapper method `insertTracciato`? What does not work for you? Please modify your question so that it has the answers to this questions and someone here would be able to help. And welcome on SO :)

Comment: Create table development(developmentName varchar(100) primary key,description varchar(100));                                                                   Create table Student(name varchar(100) primary key,dateType varchar(100),developmentName foreign key reference development(developmentName));                                                                                    The json would come in the above format:                                I want to save json into database using mybatis.

Comment: Please, check my comment again. I have chosen the wording in it very carefully. Namely, the clarification should be done to the question text itself (not via the additional comments) so that question contains all relevant information (which exactly - the comments does name it).

Comment: Can you understand now?

Comment: No, the question is still not clear. How do you invoke mybatis to execute save? You wrote that JSON is not saved but what error do you get?

Comment: Which database are you working with? To insert multiple values you need to call INSERT statement multiple times and not use `<foreach>`. If u are using Oracle then u can use `INSERT ALL INTO`