# Inserting one to many relation but XML is not proper.?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

Create table development(developmentName varchar(100) primary key,description varchar(100));
Create table Student(name varchar(100) primary key,dateType varchar(100),developmentName foreign key reference development(developmentName));

The json would come in the format

{
   "DevelopmentName":"comp",
   "description":"Descrizione Tracciatro 1",
   "Student":[
      {

```
        "name":"String",
        "dateType":"String", 
        "DevelopmentName":"comp"
     },
    {
        "name":"String",
        "date_type":"String"
        "DevelopmentName":"comp"
     }
```

]
}
: I want to save json into database using mybatis.

```
<insert id="save" parameterType="it.eng.billing.model.Development" >
insert into Development (developmentName, description) values (#{developmentName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{description,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
```

INSERT INTO student (name, dateType,developmentName)
VALUES
    
        #{option.name},#{option.dateType},#{option.developmentName}

Please can you recorrect the xml to save data into database?

Comment: This seems to be an attempt to clarify this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140683/what-is-the-xml-mapping-for-json-like-this . Please don't create new questions but instead clarify the existing one (I've provided specific instructions what is missing in the original question). This question should be deleted and original question should be modified to make it more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the xml mapping for json like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140683/what-is-the-xml-mapping-for-json-like-this)